# dir_rtl dosn"t override

Tags: css

I have a background-image for custom-menu
in the english version it works o.k (This should be the top layer so I did position:relative)

```
 #custommenu {
background-image: url([[pix:theme|header]])  ;
position:relative;
left:-18px;
top:-8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 997px;
height: 57px;
padding: 0;}
```

In the rtl.css 
I can not move the image to the right

```
.dir-rtl#custommenu {
 float:right;
 right:-34px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi i thing you should remove `float:right;`

as like this

```
.dir-rtl#custommenu {
 right:-34px;
}
```